# Avoiding quote insertion on NamedParameterJdbcTemplate parameterized query

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, namedparameterjdbctemplate

thank you for taking the time to read.

I am trying to execute a query using a JDBC connection to Snowflake via this line of code:

```
namedParamJdbcTemplate.execute(sqlQuery, paramKeyValueMap, (PreparedStatementCallback) ps -> ps.executeUpdate());
```

Here are the variables being passed to the execute method:

```
query = 'SELECT TYPE_ID, DESCRIPTION FROM LATEST.ACCOUNT_TYPE
                    WHERE DESCRIPTION IN (''AWARD'',''CONSUMER_DDA'')
                    AND SYS_SRC_OP_TIMESTAMP > :SYS_SRC_OP_TIMESTAMP'

paramKeyValueMap = ('SYS_SRC_OP_TIMESTAMP' --> 'CURRENT_DATE-365')
```

Unfortunately, this is throwing a SQL error:

```
Timestamp 'CURRENT_DATE-365' is not recognized; nested exception is net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: Timestamp 'CURRENT_DATE-365' is not recognized
```

As you can see, the error is that one of the parameters being passed to the query, <CURRENT_DATE-365> is being surrounded by quotes during runtime execution.

I tried manually executing the query without the quotes and it appears to work correctly.

Please let me know if you are aware of a way to pass parameters without the quotes.

Respectfully,
mark

Comment: I don't think you can pass the expression like that, did you try keeping CURRENT_DATE in query itself and passing 365(expecting thats the value that will change based on your needs) alone as named parameter ?

Comment: Hi Yuvaraj, thanks for your suggestion. I tried your proposed idea and the query still fails because the value, 365, is passed in and interpreted as a string. Thus the error becomes: 

SQL compilation error: error line 3 at position 60\nInvalid argument types for function '-': (DATE, VARCHAR(3))